# How do I pass arraylist of a custom object from one java class to another?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `Arraylist` of custom objects. I am trying to pass it from one java file to another. I tried the `putExtra` method and the `Parcelable` option; but I'm unable to understand `Parcelable`.

Here's my custom object:

```
public class AddValues implements Serializable{
    public int id;
    String value;

    public AddValues(int id, String value)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = "id = "+id+","+" value = "+value;
        return result;
    }

    public  int getid()
    {
        return  this.id;
    }

    public String getvalue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

And here's my code to send the `ArrayList`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothLeService.this,HomePageFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("id", data_id);
intent.putExtra("value", list);
```

Here "list" refers to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: What is you issue? Show the code where you take `list` from intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Serializable` and `Parcelable` are not the same thing, although they serve the same purpose. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable) contains an example of the Parcelable object.

The pattern employed should be followed for all Parcelable objects you want to create, changing only the `writeToParcel` and `AddValues(Parcel in)` methods. These two methods should mirror eachother, if `writeToParcel` writes an `int` then a `string`, the constructor should read an `int` then a `string`

*Parcelable*

```
public class AddValues implements Parcelable{
    private int id;
    private String value;

    // Constructor
    public AddValues (int id, String value){
        this.id = id;
        this.value= value;
   }

   // Parcelling part
   public AddValues (Parcel in){
       this.id = in.readInt();
       this.value= in.readString();
   }

   @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeInt(id);
       dest.writeString(value);
   }

   public final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public AddValues createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new AddValues(in); 
       }

       public AddValues[] newArray(int size) {
           return new AddValues[size];
       }
   };
```

}

Adding the list to an Intent extra should be simple now

*Put List extra*

```
ArrayList<AddValue> list = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothLeService.this,HomePageFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("arg_key", list);
```

*Get List extra*

```
ArrayList<AddValues> list = (ArrayList<AddValues>) intent.getSerializableExtra("arg_key");
```

*As an aside, you can use the `Pair<Integer, String>` object instead of creating an `AddValues` object. This doesn't affect the answer, but might be nice to know.*

Comment: Thanks Kevin.When I pass the intent.putExtra method, it gives an error Error:(220, 74) error: incompatible types: List<AddValues> cannot be converted to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>

Comment: No. I'll update my answer, found 2 issues in it. `List` cannot be used, as it isn't `Serializable` and there are minor changes in the Parcelable class.

Comment: Alright, awaiting response. Thanks =)

Comment: The error still persists. And the error is in PutList extra. Same error.

Comment: @SantuReddy I just ran it again without making any changes. It printed out successfully. Make sure your code is the same, and if it still doesn't work; try cleaning the project.

Comment: Its giving me the syntax error in PutList Extra. I cleaned the project and ran it again.

Comment: @SantuReddy Did you change `List` to be `ArrayList`? `ArrayList<AddValue> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes of course. I have used the Arraylist itself. With AddValue as the type.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass object instances in the intent extra using the `putExtra("key", Serializable value)` variant of the `Intent#putExtra()` method, which you are already doing here.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothLeService.this,HomePageFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("id", data_id);
intent.putExtra("value", list);
```

Now for getting this data in the other Activity you need to use `getSerializableExtra("key")` method.

```
list = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("value");
```

But if you want to use `Parcelable` see @kevins answer.